# how to overlap image on custompaint in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm a beginner at flutter. So I don't know if I'm doing this right or not!
I want to design like this -> [design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5YRP.png)

Here's my custom paint ->

```
class RPSCustomPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint_0 = Paint()
      ..color = Color.fromARGB(255, 33, 150, 243)
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    Path path_0 = Path();
    path_0.moveTo(size.width * 0.04, size.height * 1.04);
    path_0.lineTo(size.width * 0.8, size.height * 1.04);
    path_0.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.79, size.height * 0.21,
        size.width * 0.79, size.height * 0.16);
    path_0.cubicTo(size.width * 0.79, size.height * -0.01, size.width * 0.27,
        size.height * -0.18, size.width * 0.04, size.height * -0.4);
    path_0.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.05, size.height * -0.10,
        size.width * 0.04, size.height * 1.04);
    path_0.close();

    canvas.drawPath(path_0, paint_0);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

I tried to get the image on top of my *CustomPaint* but can't do it.
Here's the method I tried :

- Image in customPaint

```
CustomPaint(
                painter: RPSCustomPainter(),
                child: Image.asset(
                  'assets/images/avater/cod2.png',
                  fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                ),
              ),
```

- Custompaint and image in a Stack

```
Stack(
                children: [
                  CustomPaint(
                    child: Container(),
                    painter: RPSCustomPainter(),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                    child: Image.asset(
                      'assets/images/avater/pubg2.png',
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
```

I implemented a *Gridview.Count* and I passed those methods on its children.
Here's the output  :[my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7m16.png)

Comment: Did you check this, maybe this might help you :https://gist.github.com/netsmertia/9c588f23391c781fa1eb791f0dce0768

Comment: I tried this method. But it shows the image on its full width and height. Can't resize the image. and when I scroll back it disappears automatically. I think this is not a solution for me! But When i use an Image except custompaint it works fine!